# Java GUI for cross-platform

Tags: java, user-interface, cross-platform

Well, I want to develop cross-platform application with GUI on Java. And I want that my app will look natively as much as possible. So what GUI-library/framework I need to choose? I plan to develop for Win, Linux and Mac OS.

Comment: Swing.  Take a look at [How to Set the Look and Feel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you to use SWT - [Standard Widget Toolkit](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/). It interacts directly with the operating system, so you can have the native look and feel without any additional layer (like in SWING for example)

Answer (score 1):

The [Standard Widget Toolkit](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/) and the [Abstract Window Toolkit](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/package-summary.html) use the native widgets of the platform that it is executed on (unlike Swing).

Answer (score 0):

I would rather try to go with Java FX for that purpose althrough I don't know how much native is Java Fx, but heres a simple overview:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/overview/index.html